# Redirect with value of radio button

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code I am working on

```
<html>
<script>
var submit = document.getElementById('btnFormSubmit');
submit.addEventListener('click', submitForm);

function submitForm(event){
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();

var href = '',
inputs = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
     if(inputs[i].getAttribute('name') == 'scenarionum' && inputs[i].checked){
         href = inputs[i].getAttribute('data-href');
         value= inputs[i].getAttribute('value');
         window.location = href;
     }
}
}

</script>

<head>
<title>Hello</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" name="start" action="./test.pl">
<div class="Folder">
<input type="radio" name="scenarionum" value="Run Suite" data-href="test.pl"/>Suite</div>
<input type="submit" value="Run" id="btnFormSubmit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is working fine. When I am clicking the Submit button its taking me to the page "test.pl" but I want to redirect it along with the value of the radio button (which is "Run Suite" in this case")

please tell me the modifications in the javascript to redirect to test.pl along with the value "Run Suite"

Comment: Do you actually need the script, the submit button will automatically post the value of the form inputs to the page set by the action-attribute.

Answer (score 1):

delete all the JavaScript and the form will work as expected.  HTML Forms already know how to submit values to a script.

Answer (score 0):

Add the value to the url as a request param:

```
 if(inputs[i].getAttribute('name') == 'scenarionum' && inputs[i].checked){
     href = inputs[i].getAttribute('data-href');
     value= inputs[i].getAttribute('value');
     window.location = href + "?scenarionum=" + value;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**SEND GET**

You can just add it to the URL like this:

```
window.location = href+"?value="+value;
```

[Example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24rJ4/)

**SEND POST**

If you want the form to send a POST you can do the following:

```
if(inputs[i].getAttribute('name') == 'scenarionum' && inputs[i].checked){
     document.getElementById("myForm").action = inputs[i].getAttribute('data-href');
     document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

You also have to give your form an id, so it can be found with getElementByID, or you can use

```
document.getElementsByName("start")[0].
```

[Example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5NKG/)

Comment: You should read the url on "./test.pl" to get the value, since it is not a POST but a GET.

Answer (score 0):

Change your submit input with the following. it works, just tested.

```
<input type="submit" value="Run" id="btnFormSubmit" onclick="document.forms['start'].action=document.getElementById('scenarionum').checked ? './test.pl?scenarionum=' + document.getElementById('scenarionum').value : './test.pl'" />
```